# Use MS Exchange assigned tasks in Linux

Tags: linux, microsoft-outlook, exchange, tasks, evolution

My company uses MS Exchange for Businesses with an OWA web frontend. My boss sometimes assigns me tasks via the desktop Outlook and I would somehow like to use these tasks. 
I am using Linux (Evolution for E-Mail and calendar). Those assigned tasks arrive me in the form of a plain text mail without attachments. The official web frontend OWA [does not support assigned or shared tasks, either](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-Tasks-in-Outlook-com-or-Outlook-on-the-web-6e8a991b-ea62-4009-a7f7-62b70a57ec18). Is there someway to use (import, update, mark as resolved) assigned tasks without having to use the Outlook desktop client?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint?

Comment: @BastianW: No, just the ordinary office365 business thing.